# Why is there no community dedicated to atheism on Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion

I mean there are tons of religious communities on Stack Exchange like Biblical Hermeneutics, Buddhism, Hinduism, Islam etc. Why not a community for atheism, where every religion and its practices can be questioned in purely logical terms?

Comment: Why haven't you started one, then?

Comment: you can check proposals [here](https://area51.stackexchange.com) if its not available you could submit one and try to build a community

Comment: It's up to you to make one ;)

Comment: As someone who called themselves an atheist for years, I'm not sure what such a community would discuss. There's already philosophy and (I believe) a logic site. To me, this seems like asking why there isn't a site for people who *don't* cook since there a site for people who do cook.

Comment: ok i created one. So give me a review https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/114485/modern-day-thinkers

Comment: Are the people so butthurt because of word "Atheism" that they downvoted this to -17.

Comment: Related: [Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/tags/religion/hot) SE

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There was an [Area 51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2732/atheism) for Atheism but it didn't receive enough support to get off the ground. There are nine other failed proposals that didn't make it that far.

It would be worth reading about that proposal first to try to determine why it was not successful to avoid the same fate. It seems likely there is simply insufficient shared credo between athiests.

You could try proposing a humanism site instead, that might gain more traction, although that too has previously been proposed on several occasions and failed each time, the mechanism would be the same i.e. via Area 51.

Some of the information in this answer comes from Robert Cartaino and was originally provided in a comment to this answer.

Comment: I created one proposal. Don't know if its okay. https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/114485/genesis-of-gods

Comment: Doesn't really sound much like atheism to me but I guess we'll see. If you can garner a community around your proposal it will likely launch.

Comment: That A51 proposal actually got started and the site was active for a while. It was shut down later, mostly due to very low activity if I remember correctly.

Comment: **Correction:** There have been **10 proposals about atheism,** including one that finally made it to public beta but failed utterly as a site. The last proposal was less than a year ago — not to mention seven failed proposals involving Humanism.

Answer (score 6):

You can propose an Atheism Stack Exchange on Area 51.

It has been tried a few times before, however, and so far all of these attempts have failed.
It was hard to get good example questions. Religions usually come with rules and stories, so there is plenty of material to ask questions about. Atheism, by contrast, does not have rules or a canon. There is simply a lot less to ask and answer about.

Many of the example questions on the Atheism proposals that I've seen, would also fit on Philosophy.SE. Philosophy.SE also has an [atheism tag](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atheism). So the subject *is* covered on Stack Exchange.